# Have one program start up and run many instances of another java program

Tags: java, server, client

I've been programming a client-server setup, and I'd like to be able to have a overarching java program that allows me to boot up a couple instances of my servers and create respective clients to connect to them, without having to explicitly run the .jar files into my terminal by hand.

So right now for my system, I would type the following stuff into 4 separate terminal windows

(Terminal 1)

```
java -jar Server.jar
```

(Terminal 2)

```
java -jar Server.jar
```

(Client 1)

```
java aClient
```

(Client 2)

```
java bClient
```

I'm fairly new to working with java, so forgive me if the answer is obvious

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself if Java is the way to go in this instance? Perhaps boot up the servers and clients in docker containers, and orchestrate them via a `docker-compose` file? :)

Comment: Does the client-server couple live together? What i mean is when the client is closing, should the server also be closed?

Comment: This looks more like a script kind of thing than java.

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens Ah okay. Would you have any recommendations of what to use then? I hate to admit it, but I am also rather inexperienced along those lines as well

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for this. It is very easy to start up other programs with it and you can also check their logs. It works like this:

```
Process = ProcessBuilder()
                .directory("somedir")
                .command("java", "-jar", "myjar.jar")
                .start()
```